# how to use geom_smooth in ggplot 2 for a subset of values in a data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with 3 keys Names, Week, Hours. There are 6 names and I would like to geom_smooth() the scattered plot, but do not want to include values associated with 1 name in the smoothing. It is a graph to see how the hours of 1 person affect the hours of the team.

```
my data looks something like this
a<-
Week<date>   Names<chr> Hours<dbl>
2017-02-27    Miki      4.50  
2017-02-27    Mouse     1.20  
2017-02-27    Rocks     3.70  
2017-03-06    Miki      5.80  
2017-03-06    Mouse     2.20  
2017-03-06    Rocks     11.00

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(a, aes(x=Week, y=Hours))+
 geom_point(aes(color=Names))+
 geom_smooth(aes(group_by(subset(Hours, !("Rocks" %in% Names)))))+
 geom_smooth(aes(group_by(subset(Hours, ("Rocks" %in% Names)))))+
 scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y/%m/%d", date_breaks="1 month", date_minor_breaks = "1 week")
```

I get this error code when running the above:

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify your dataframe to exclude/filter 'Rocks' for the 2nd and 3rd layer.

```
a %>% ggplot(aes(x = Week, y = Hours)) + 
 geom_point(aes(color = Names)) +
 geom_smooth(data = a %>% filter(!Names %in% 'Rocks')) + 
 geom_smooth(data = a %>% filter(Names %in% 'Rocks'))
```

Comment: Nice. Works like a charm. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

```
Week <- c("2017-02-27","2017-02-27","2017-02-27","2017-03-06","2017-03-06",
      "2017-03-06")

Names <- rep(c("Miki","Mouse","Rocks"),2)

Hours <- c(4.5,1.2,3.7,5.8,2.2,11)

dt <- data.frame(Week = Week,
             Names = Names,
             Hours = Hours)

dt$Week <- as.Date(dt$Week)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dt,aes(x = Week, y = Hours)) + 
  geom_point(aes(group = Names,color = Names)) + 
  geom_smooth(data = subset(dt, dt$Names != "Rocks"),method = "loess", se = FALSE)
```